# little error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me in this minute error.
I wrote this, (which is not working),

```
SELECT sum(case when SD.order_id>0 then 1 else 0 end) as SD.customer_id  
FROM tbl_order_lead_send_detail SD
```

but, this query is working fine.

```
SELECT sum(case when order_id>0 then 1 else 0 end) as customer_id  
FROM tbl_order_lead_send_detail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is this:

```
as SD.customer_id
```

You might consider writing:

```
as `SD.customer_id`
```

**EDIT**

Becuase you cannot have `.` in the column names. If you have them as a string it works. The `.` is used for columns in tables.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT sum(case when SD.order_id>0 then 1 else 0 end) as customer_id FROM tbl_order_lead_send_detail, SD
```